# how do I enable transaction QR codes in the Parity Wallet browser app?

Tags: parity, parity-wallet, parity-signer, qrcode

I'm Parity 1.7 installed via Homebrew on MacOS. I cannot see the QR code for signing transactions. How do I enable this feature?

```
Parity//v1.7.0-beta-5f2cabd-20170727/x86_64-macos/rustc1.18.0
```

I see this:

[image: What I see]

But not this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download the Parity Signer app for Android form Google Play or iOS from the AppStore.
2. Create a new account with the mobile app.
3. Backup the account from the mobile app in a secure location.
4. Make redundant backups in even more secure locations.
5. Make sure your backups are recoverable.
6. Open your Parity desktop wallet in your browser.
7. Go to ACCOUNTS, click NEW ACCOUNT, and chose EXTERNAL ACCOUNT.
8. Scan the QR-code from the mobile app.
9. Now you can sign with your mobile, air-gapped app.